# Winston logger not write to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I want to use `winston` logger in `node` app for log error to file. But `winston` not write to file.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
             transports: [
                new (winston.transports.Console)(),
                new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
              ]
            });

 logger.error('test');
```

file `somefile.log` is created but empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a level in the constructor.

```
var tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
var log = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            colorize: true,
            level: 'info'
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            filename: 'somefile.log',
            level: 'error'
        })
    ]
});


log.error('test'); // writes to log and console out
log.info('testing info'); // writes just in console
```