# Winston doesn't write to file

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I want to log errors in a file in an application made with nodeJS and Express. After a few searches I found that Winston is a good library to do that. I found [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-winston-to-log-node-js-applications).

But when I try `winston.error('test')`, the message is in the console but the log file is not created (so there is nothing in it). I searched on this site and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956367/winston-logger-not-write-to-file) that seems similar to mine but I can't spot the difference between the answer and my code.

This is my code :

```
// src/config/winston.js

const appRoot = require('app-root-path')
const winston = require('winston')

let options = {
  file: {
    level: 'error',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/error.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
}

let logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
})

logger.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding) {
    logger.error(message);
  },
}

module.exports = logger
```

I did this to try :

```
// src/api/meal_validation.js
...
winston.error('test')
...
```

Comment: Works for me. Do make sure that the `${appRoot}/logs/` directory actually exists, and that `winston` in `winston.error()` is the exported `logger` reference (and not the result of `require('winston')`).

Comment: Thank you @robertklep my path was bad..... -_-